# Batch File Replace text in text file but keep first word/column

Tags: file, variables, batch-file, replace

Ok guys. I am new to stack. searched for an answer but couldn't find one. 
My txt file

```
CUMBS02778607   DVD/SLS34142072,Z5
CUMBS02778844   SHIP/25/02/14/HR/15,Z5
CUMBS02780058   DVD/SLS34142200,ISSUE 9,Z5
CUMBS02779867   SHIP/27/02/14/CAM/49,Z5
CUMBS02779883   SHIP/27/02/14/CAM/48,Z5
CUMBS02779816   SHIP/27/02/14/CAM/36,Z7
CUMBS02779948   SHIP/27/02/14/CAM/46,Z5
CUMBS02780309   DVD/SLS34142262,Z5
CUMBS02780218   DVD/SLS34142231,Z5
CUMBS02780406   DVD/SLS34142266-267,Z5
CUMBS02779956   SHIP/27/02/14/CAM/50,Z5
CUMBS02779743   DVD/SLS34142181-182,Z5
CUMBS02779611   SHIP/27/02/14/PRO/02,Z4
CUMBS02780155   DVD/SLS34142191-193,Z5
CUMBS02777848   ORD.7737623,REF.62664,SLS34141962,Z7
```

contains the following line:

```
CUMBS02778607   DVD/SLS34142072,Z5
```

My Script Running in batch is as follows. Search for .....SLS and replace it with just SLS

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "search=*SLS"
set "replace=SLS"
set "textfile=new.txt"
set "newfile=output.txt"

(for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /n "^" "%textfile%"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>"%newfile%"
type "%newfile%"
```

The problem is file returns and throws away the CUMBS******** Number. I need to keep that is a variable and put it back in the start of the string. This removes any junk before the characters SLS. Lines 
Guys any help would be appreciated.

Example of text returned. lines afterwards starting like 2: , 5: etc and not starting with CUMB****** I will delete.

```
SLS34142072,Z5
2:CUMBS02778844 SHIP/25/02/14/HR/15,Z5
SLS34142200,ISSUE 9,Z5
4:CUMBS02779867 SHIP/27/02/14/CAM/49,Z5
5:CUMBS02779883 SHIP/27/02/14/CAM/48,Z5
6:CUMBS02779816 SHIP/27/02/14/CAM/36,Z7
7:CUMBS02779948 SHIP/27/02/14/CAM/46,Z5
SLS34142262,Z5
SLS34142231,Z5
SLS34142266-267,Z5
11:CUMBS02779956    SHIP/27/02/14/CAM/50,Z5
SLS34142181-182,Z5
13:CUMBS02779611    SHIP/27/02/14/PRO/02,Z4
SLS34142191-193,Z5
SLS34141962,Z7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "search=*SLS"
set "replace=SLS"
set "textfile=new.txt"
set "newfile=output.txt"

(for /f "usebackq tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%textfile%") do (
    set "line=%%b"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(%%a !line!
    endlocal
))>"%newfile%"
type "%newfile%"
```

You have it almost done.

Using `*SLS` is asking to delete from start of line up to SLS, so it deletes the `CUMBS*` field. Instead, split the input record on the tab, keeping the first field and doing the replacemente only on the second one.

The numbering comes from `findstr /n` As it is not needed, removed

Comment: Thanks MC ND. It Works! Damn I was actually close. Can you please explain the [ "usebackq tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%textfile%") do (
    set "line=%%b"section] of the code. How I understand is Token 1 is 1st column pulled into %%a and the * is the rest pulled into %%b , You then run the replace against %%b and just add %%a back again ?

Comment: @Dark_seth, Yes, this is what is done. And uses `usebackq` because, as the filename is enclosed in doble quotes (in case there are spaces), it will be taken as a string and not as a file to be readed.